# Python: convert buffer type of SQLITE column into string

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.6

I am new to Python 2.6. I have been trying to fetch date *datetime* value which is in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:m:ss` format back in my Python program. On checking the column type in Python I get the error: `'buffer' object has no attribute 'decode'`. I want to use the `strptime()` function to split the date data and use it but I can't find how to convert a buffer to string. The following is a sample of my code (also available [here](http://pastie.org/5360165)):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("mrp.db.db", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
cursor = conn.cursor()
qryT = """
    SELECT dateDefinitionTest FROM t
    WHERE IDproject = 4 AND IDstatus = 5
    ORDER BY priority, setDate DESC
"""
rec = (4,4)
cursor.execute(qryT,rec)
resultsetTasks = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()  # closing the resultset
for item in resultsetTasks:
    taskDetails = {}
    _f = item[10].decode("utf-8")
```

The exception I get is:

```
'buffer' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Please show your code and the exact error.

Comment: http://pastie.org/5360165 **dateDefinitionTest** is a sqlite3 field of _datetime_

Comment: Error i get: ** 'buffer' object has no attribute 'decode' **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what your problem may be. The following is a working example of what you are trying to achieve, which hopefully will help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE t (dateDefinitionTest DATETIME)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES (?)", (datetime.datetime.now(),))
query = "SELECT dateDefinitionTest FROM t"
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    print(repr(dt))
    print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
cursor.close()
```

which outputs:

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 11, 16, 40, 26, 788966)
2012-11-11 16:40:26.788966
```

Comment: I did same but getting the error: **strptime() argument 1 must be string, not buffer** . I m using Python 2.6

Comment: What I did, i assigned row[0] in another variable: **f = row[0][:]** that converted _buffer_ into str and then **strptime** accepted the value.

Comment: My example was tested with Python 2.7. It may be that Python 2.6 returns a buffer instead of a string.

Comment: yes seems version issue. Can you please tell how to format **datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 11, 13, 9, 29, 141720)**? strftime() does not work as it's being returned as tuple

Comment: Just apply `strftime()` to the parsed `datetime`. See the updated example in the answer.

Comment: gives error: **'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime'** Issue is it is taking **datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 11, 16, 40, 26, 788966)** as tuple rather than of type datetime

Comment: You must be using [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/time.html#time.strptime) which returns a `tuple`. You need to use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) which returns a `datetime.datetime` (just as a side note, `datetime.datetime.strptime` actually uses `time.strptime` internally in its implementation).

Comment: This is the faulty line: **datetime.strptime(_datepart,'%Y-%m-%d')," at ",datetime.strptime(_timepart,'%H:%M:%S')**

Comment: I guesss I found the reason. I was importing as **from datetime import datetime,date, time** and i think last import was causing the overriding of some function within *datetime*. By removing extra module import it's  now seems to work

Answer (score 2):

Your problem's root cause is considering the 'buffer' object gotten from Sqlite database as a 'string' object, the string object has the encode() method, but 'buffer' object has no this method.
What your need do is simple: just convert the 'buffer' object to string object, and it's not difficult, only add one line in your codes:

tempString=str(item[10])

_f = tempString.decode("utf-8")

I encountered the same problem today, and googled directed me to here, and  found no suitable answer yet. So provide it here.
The sqlite record data's type is buffer or string is decided by how we construct our db table, and the sqlite version, and the sqlite db plugin's version, so you test result is different from Pedro Romano's. But any way, just add this line: tempString=str(item[10]), it could force the system use it as a string.